# After the latest updates on or about Nov 4th Ubuntu 16.04 Unity doesn't accept my password

Tags: drivers, unity, nvidia, graphics, login

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with Unity environment.

The latest updates included a driver update to Nvidia graphics.  After the updates, Ubuntu will not login nor accept any password.  It loops back to the login screen.

The graphics on my computer is on the motherboard.  I am using the latest kernel - 4.4.0-45. No matter if go to a previous kernel, with Nvidia driver selected, I cannot use Unity now.

How to correct this?  How to I revert back to the previous Nvidia version?  I am running Ubuntu dual-booted with Mint 18 Cinnamon.

How can I access Ubuntu if I cannot login?  It appears that Ubuntu 16.04 (latest updates - Nvidia) is not compatible with Unity.

Comment: Are you using the Nouveau or proprietary drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all who responded thanks. I have since removed Unity and am currently running Mint 18 XFCE.  So far, no problems.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem yesterday. 
X (lightdm) has started with displaying the Nvidia splash screen. So the nvidia-driver had worked in general.
The logon screen appears. But then after logon on X, the screen was black and then the X (lightdm) has started again with displaying the Nvidia splash screen and the logon screen.

For me it was the nvidia-driver. The latest upgrade had installed `nvidia-current` which was `nvidia-304` which had failed restart lightdm while X-logon.

But simply installing `nvidia-367` or `nvidia-370` as suggested often, is not the real solution with all Nvidia GPUs.

We first must detect what GPU is really in use. So follow the instructions on [How to install the latest Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus).

For me it was:

```
axel@arichter:~$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation G92M [GeForce GTX 260M] [10de:0618] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

So a `GeForce GTX 260M` is in use and so [NVDIA driver search page](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx) told me that for `GeForce 200M Series (Notebooks)` driver `Version:  340.98` must be used.

So `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and then  `sudo apt-get install nvidia-340` solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>;

Enter your login and password;

Enter `sudo apt purge nvidia*`;

reboot;

reinstall nvidia drivers

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem yesterday, to install the right drivers after you log in, just type:
sudo apt-get install nvidia-367

this is the newest driver, the older one, which is not working with this kernel is nvidia-304.132

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it:

1.)  Boot to Grub

2.)  Choose recovery Kernel under advanced ubuntu options

3.)  In the menu that appears, choose to use the fallback graphics mode.  This will mount the disk.

4.)  When the menu reappears, drop to a root shell and purge the nvidia driver like this:

sudo apt purge nvidia* (the asterisk is required)

5.)  Reboot and you should be using Nouveau since its the only driver left.